# I wrote this code and need to know if there is synchronization problem in updating the variable value?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int value = 10;

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        value = value + 100;
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        value = value - 100;
        printf("PARENT: value = %d \n", value); //Line A
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

I wrote this code and need to know if there is synchronization problem in updating the variable value

Comment: After a `fork`, the parent and the child have separate instances of `value`. There is no interaction between them through it.

Comment: If you were to use `clone` with appropriate options instead of `fork`, you could have the parent and child share memory.  Then they would share the same instance of `value` and there would definitely be a synchronization problem.  The parent could print `10`, or `-90`, or `110`, or perhaps some other garbage.

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Comment: In general, whenever two threads access the same data, there is *always* a synchronization problem until you can prove that there isn't, either by using locks or some other mechanism that makes explicit atomicity guarantees.  Ordinary C variable accesses don't.

Comment: so if  i access global variable through two threads there will be a  synchronization problem  right? why is that? how to solve it?

Comment: This will be discussed in literally every book or tutorial on multithreading; I don't care to rewrite such a tutorial here.  The short answer is "locking".  But do not attempt to write multithreaded code until you have thoroughly learned about the issue (at a deeper level than an SO post).

Comment: @Rashmikagamage: If you no longer want your question to be seen on the site, just **delete** it. There is no reason to invalidate its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you fork, parent and child are two different processes, `value` of parent and `value` of child are two different instances, changing one of them does not affect the other, we can't realy talk about synchronization in this case.

As for the processes themselves there is a degree of synchronization since the parent process waits for the child process before continuing.

You are missing `#include <sys/wait.h>`.

Comment: ... since the parent process can but is not required to wait. Waiting is a function of application design.

Comment: Thank you very much